# Learning Python The Hard Way, Exercise 43 object() takes no parameters

Tags: python

I'm working through Zed's Learnpythonthehardway HTML version. I'm currently on Exercise #43 but I've stripped away some of the scenes from a game and I'm having an issue.

I'm getting the error: `"object() takes no parameters" at the line 'a_map = Map('empty_scene')`

Here's my code:

```
from sys import exit

class Scene(object):

def enter(self):
    print "This scene is not yet configured. Subclass it and implement\
enter()."
    exit(1)

class Engine(object):

def _init_(self, scene_map):
    self.scene_map = scene_map

def play(self):
    current_scene = self.scene_map.opening_scene()
    last_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene('finished')

    while current_scene != last_scene:
        next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()
        current_scene = self.scene_map.next_scene(next_scene_name)

        current_scene.enter()   

class EmptyScene(Scene):

def enter(self):
    pass

class FinishScene(Scene):

def enter(self):
    pass

class Map(object): 

scenes = {
    'empty_scene': EmptyScene(),
    'finished': FinishScene(),
}

def _init_(self, start_scene):
    self.start_scene = start_scene

def next_scene(self, scene_name):
    val = Map.scenes.get(scene_name)
    return val

def opening_scene(self):
    return self.next_scene(self.start_scene)    

a_map = Map('empty_scene')
a_game = Engine(a_map)
a_game.play()
```

Comment: Shouldn't the `_init_`s be double underscored? `__init__`?

Comment: `__init__` with two underscores on each side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your indents look way off.

```
class EmptyScene(Scene):

def enter(self):
    pass
```

should be:

```
class EmptyScene(Scene):

    def enter(self):
        pass
```

Map isn't really associated with _init_, which should be __init__

```
def _init_(self, start_scene):
    self.start_scene = start_scene
```

So, instead of calling Map._init_, your Map(xxx) ends up calling object.__init__, which does not have a parameter and your own function definition isn't taken into consideration.

try:

```
class Map(object): 

    scenes = {
        'empty_scene': EmptyScene(),
        'finished': FinishScene(),
    }

    def __init__(self, start_scene):
        self.start_scene = start_scene
```

and while you are at it, indent all your def that have a self (meaning methods), 4 spaces to be under the classes because your whole code has that problem.

remember: indent 4 spaces and double underscores to the __init__ method.

Good luck

Comment: My indents are correct in my text editor - I just messed it up when I put it in the question. Sorry about that!

Comment: I assume the problem was the \_init_ vs \__init__ then?  Because that would do that as well.  Yes, you have to be very careful with indents here for Python.  To be honest, I was puzzled that you'd get all the way to ex #43 without catching the def indentation, but stranger things have happened.  This is btw one of the cases where even seasoned Python programmers get confused easily - the error with number of params is shown at the calling location, but you aren't told the location of the function which is not being called correctly (I've gotten bit by the no-param-on-object init before).